# Java - Error by adding elements into List

Tags: java, list, exception, javafx

I'm getting `UnsupportedOperationException` when I add an elemnt into my `ObservableList<List<String>>`.

The code *(here I'm trying to add columns in my dynamic tableview)*:

```
private ObservableList<List<String>> fnlData; 
.
.
fnlData = FXCollections.observableList(jdata);
.
.
public void addColumn(){
        for (int i = 0; i < fnlData.size(); i++){
            if (fnlData.get(i)!=null && fnlData.get(i).size() > indexC) {
                fnlData.get(i).add(indexC, "");  // <- here occurs the error 
            }
        }
        finalTable.getSelectionModel().clearSelection();
        finalTable.getItems().clear();
        finalTable.getColumns().clear();
        createColumns(clms++);
        finalTable.getItems().addAll(fnlData);
    }
```

Comment: Where does "indexC" come from ?

Comment: what do you mean? indexC gives the number of the selected column

Comment: What type of list is `jdata`? Could it be that it is some kind of immutable list? `fnlData` forwards the `addAll` to the backing list `jdata`. If the backing list does not support the operation, an `UnsupportedOperationException` should be the result.

Comment: public List<List<String>> jdata = new LinkedList<>();

Comment: What type of list is the innerlist of `jdata`? (i.e. the `List<String>`)

Comment: What do yout mean with type of list? its a List<String> ?

Comment: List is just the interface. You have many implementations of the List (ArrayList, LinkedList, ImmutableArrayList, etc), and some of them don't have the add method (well, they have it, but they just throw an unsupportedOperaationException

Comment: Excuse me, I meant to ask what the implementing class was. (i.e. what is the output of `System.out.println(jdata.get(0).getClass().getName());`) (for example, it might just be: `java.util.Collections$UnmodifiableRandomAccessList`)

Comment: I would be tempted to create intermediate variable `var = fnlData.get(i);` to check what is actually stored in your `ObservableList`, it seems that it is not recognised correctly...

Comment: @ljgw it says: java.util.Arrays$ArrayList

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I solved it...

I changed this:

```
private List<List<String>> jdata = new LinkedList<>();
String[] splitted;
.
.
splitted=(lines.split(";"));
jdata.add(Arrays.asList(splitted));
```

into this:

```
private List<List<String>> jdata = new LinkedList<>();
String[] splitted;
.
.
splitted=(lines.split(";"));
LinkedList ll = new LinkedList(Arrays.asList(splitted));
jdata.add(ll);
```

Because the inner list (`List<String>`) of jdata was a ArrayList, but I needed a LinkedList...

Thanks to ljgw

Answer (score 0):

An implementation of a collection is free to implement as many operations as it pleases, throwing an `UnsupportedOperationException` if the operation is not implemented. I advise you to check the documentation of the particular collection you are using.